# Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnote sync with Rainy or Grauphel Nextcloud app

Tags: 20.04, sync, nextcloud, gnote

After the Tomboy Ubuntu application was discontinued there is Gnote as replacement. But it lacks the api synchronization service (yet?) which was present in 18.04 Tomboy. This I used with the Nextcloud Grauphel app on both the Ubuntu desktop and Android Tomdroid.

I was stuck with ubuntu 18.04 for a long period of time due to this and other discontinued applications but I had to upgrade recently.

The Gnote gitlab page and the Gnote wiki page give no clue, if there is any TODO list of if the server sync will be an option in near future.

I am using the Tomdroid Android app and this in turn offers no WebDAV sync. Local directory sync is no option for me on both Android neither on Ubuntu.

The Tomboy-ng is a very weak replacement too offering even less sync options.
I am stuck with the question how to use my thousands of notes now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a dirty workaround and installed latest available Tomboy Notes from deb.
https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/tomboy/download

First I need to manually install all dependencies, which were luckily only matter of "apt install".

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tomboy:
> tomboy depends on libappindicator0.1-cil; however:
> Package libappindicator0.1-cil is not installed.
> tomboy depends on libdbus-glib2.0-cil (>= 0.6); however:
> Package libdbus-glib2.0-cil is not installed.
> tomboy depends on libdbus2.0-cil (>= 0.8.1); however:
> Package libdbus2.0-cil is not installed.
> tomboy depends on libgconf2.0-cil (>= 2.24.0); however:
> Package libgconf2.0-cil is not installed.
> tomboy depends on libglib2.0-cil (>= 2.12.40); however:
> Package libglib2.0-cil is not installed.
> tomboy depends on libgmime2.6-cil; however:
> Package libgmime2.6-cil is not installed.
> tomboy depends on libgtk2.0-cil (>= 2.12.40); however:
> Package libgtk2.0-cil is not installed.
> tomboy depends on libgtkspell0; however:
> Package libgtkspell0 is not installed.
> tomboy depends on libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil (>= 1.0); however:
> Package libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil is not installed.
> tomboy depends on libmono-addins0.2-cil (>= 1.0); however:
> Package libmono-addins0.2-cil is not installed.
> tomboy depends on libmono-cairo4.0-cil (>= 4.0.4.1); however:
> Package libmono-cairo4.0-cil is not installed.
> tomboy depends on libmono-posix4.0-cil (>= 4.6.1.3); however:
> Package libmono-posix4.0-cil is not installed.
> tomboy depends on gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2); however:
> Package gconf2 is not installed.

Only the libgconf2.0-cil has no source in current 20.04 repos, so downloaded and installed from here:
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/universe/base/libgconf2.0-cil

I am back to normal.
IMHO Gnote should implement the Tomboy web service sync to be considered full replacement.